# Can AutoMapper be configured to reuse a calculated reference property?

Tags: c#, automapper

At present I don't have control over either object I'm mapping to or from, so changing them is currently not an option. I am trying to setup a mapping where about a dozen properties are taken from a single object in an array that has to be calculated. My mapping looks akin to this right now:

```
.ForMember(d => d.CountyName,    o => o.MapFrom(x => x.TerritoryAndCounty.Options.OrderByDescending(y => y.Selected).FirstOrDefault()?.CountyName)))
.ForMember(d => d.County,        o => o.MapFrom(x => x.TerritoryAndCounty.Options.OrderByDescending(y => y.Selected).FirstOrDefault()?.County)))
.ForMember(d => d.TerritoryCode, o => o.MapFrom(x => x.TerritoryAndCounty.Options.OrderByDescending(y => y.Selected).FirstOrDefault()?.TerritoryCode)))
.ForMember(d => d.Address,       o => o.MapFrom(x => x.Location.Address))...
```

As you can see, the mapping will have to calculate the same piece of code over and over again for each property, taking a different final property each time. Given there are hundreds of properties (I know, yuck) I want to avoid doing it in one big ConstructUsing() statement. Performance is also a concern, so I would like to be able to determine the correct territoryAndCountyOption only once.

Is there an ability to create a variable when you begin mapping that you can use during the mapping? I don't know if projections would help here, but this isn't connecting to a database, and I want to specify the correct territory in the mapping, not in each Mapper.Map call. Am I thinking about this the wrong way? Is there are better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of an automapper way to pre-calculate the field for you.  How I would approach this problem would be to create a TerritoryAndCountyOptionsDto object, and if you NEED the flattened properties, simply add them as getter-only properties:

```
// Main DTO...
public TerritoryAndCountyOptions TerritoryAndCountyOptions { get; set; }
public string CountyName => TerritoryAndCountyOptions?.CountyName;

// Mapping for main object
.ForMember(d => d.TerritoryAndCountyOptions, o => o.MapFrom(x => x.TerritoryAndCounty.Options.OrderByDescending(y => y.Selected).FirstOrDefault())
```

You can make the TerritoryAndCountyOptions property internal rather than public if you wish to hide it.

Comment: Hmm, if I understand what you are saying this would involve changing my destination object, right? My current direction is that I'm not to change either the source or the destination object. Perhaps I could use this approach with an intermediary object?

Comment: My solution doesn't change the public surface of the destination object, but it will need something. I wouldn't use an intermediate object as you'd need to explicitly map twice, thereby losing most of the advantage of having your mapping done for you.

Comment: Hmm, not the public surface, but I'd still need to change the classes themselves... I *might* be able to swing that. For now I implemented a set of private classes, created maps from the service to those, then maps from the private classes to the result object, then I used a construct using on the map from the service to the result that returns a double mapper.map to get through it all while still being a single Mapper.Map call when used by the consuming classes. Thanks for your help!